# android - I want to send data from recyclerview adapter from fragment to fragment opening new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I want to send data from `RecyclerView` adapter to new `Fragment`. I succeeded in doing so, but why was the result of the collision in the previous fragment?

the least your attention is very big and meaningful to me :)

as shown below:

[image: this is the replace result of the new fragment]
[image]

I want the fragment to open up new fragments like `WhatsApp`, `Instagram`, etc.

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Adapter;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.HomeFragment;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.HomeFragmentDetail;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Job;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;

import java.util.List;


public class HomeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Job> jobList;

    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Job> jobs){
        this.context = context;
        jobList = jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.home_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HomeRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Job job = jobList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(job.getTitle());
    holder.namaPerusahaan.setText(job.getNamaPerusahaan());
    holder.kriteria_1.setText(job.getKriteria_1());
    holder.kriteria_2.setText(job.getKriteria_2());
    holder.kriteria_3.setText(job.getKriteria_3());
    holder.gaji.setText(job.getGaji());
    holder.lokasi.setText(job.getLokasi());
    holder.tanggal.setText(job.getTanggal());

    String img_logoLink = job.getImg_logo();
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(img_logoLink) // URL
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                                .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).centerCrop().dontAnimate()
//                         .centerCrop(), .crossFade(), .thumbnail(), .dontAnimate(), .dontTransform() BitmapTransformation(.circleCrop())
                )
                .into(holder.img_logo); //TARGET GAMBAR YANG NAK DIUBAH

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jobList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         TextView title;
         TextView namaPerusahaan;
         TextView lokasi;
         TextView kriteria_1;
         TextView kriteria_2;
         TextView kriteria_3;
         TextView gaji;
         ImageView img_logo;
         TextView tanggal;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView, final Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            context = ctx;
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
            namaPerusahaan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.namaPerusahaanID);
            kriteria_1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.satuTv);
            kriteria_2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duaTv);
            kriteria_3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tigaTv);
            gaji = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gajiID);
            lokasi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lokasiID);
            img_logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_logoID);
            tanggal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tanggalID);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    HomeFragmentDetail fragmentDetail = new HomeFragmentDetail();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    Job job = jobList.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    bundle.putSerializable("job", job);
                    fragmentDetail.setArguments(bundle);

                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//          fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragmenthome, fragmentDetail);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

////                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeDetailActivity.class);
////                    intent.putExtra("job", job);
////                    ctx.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**HomeFragmentDetail.java**

```
package com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Model.Job;
import com.mimdudin.carekkerje.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * to handle interaction events.
 */
public class HomeFragmentDetail extends Fragment {

    private TextView tvDeskripsi;
    private TextView tvIndustri;

    public HomeFragmentDetail() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragmentDetail newInstance(){
        HomeFragmentDetail homeFragmentDetail = new HomeFragmentDetail();
        return homeFragmentDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_fragment_detail, container, false);
        tvDeskripsi = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeskripsi);
        tvIndustri = view.findViewById(R.id.tvIndustri);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        Job job = (Job) bundle.getSerializable("job");

        String PostID = job.getId_post();
        String titleID = job.getTitle();

        tvDeskripsi.setText(PostID);
        tvIndustri.setText(titleID);

        return view;


//    DataHolder dataholder=new DataHolder("1","TestName");
//    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
//    bundle.putSerializable("obj",dataholder);

//    Fragment fragment=new FragmentB();
//    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//    fragmentManager = getActivity(). getSupportFragmentManager();
//    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager .beginTransaction();
//    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
//    fragmentTransaction.commit();

        //Job job = (Job) getIntent.getSerializableExtra("job");

//        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
//        Job job = (Job) bundle.getSerializable("job");
//        String jobID = job.getId_post();
//        String titleID = job.getTitle();



    }

}

}
```

Comment: From the code I can see that you have a `HomeFragment`, a `HomeRecyclerView (and an adapter) ` and a `HomeDetailFragment`.

You also want that when an item in recyler view is clicked HomeDetailFragment should be fragment should be opened, right?

Comment: Yesss. You are absolutely right. But I am having trouble in opening new fragment for detailfragment, the result is above homefragment

Comment: assign background color to parent layout of your HomeDetailFragment and HomeFragment

Comment: Lol. You are right, I should just change the background color hahahahaha 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

In the code where you replace `HomeDetailFragment`, call addToBackStack() like this

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragmenthome, fragmentDetail);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);    // add this line to your code
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here is a short explanation from android developer docs for [Providing Proper Back Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

> When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the
>   user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent
>   transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action (such
>   as removing a fragment if the transaction added it).

#### Solution 2:

If there is no hard-and-fast requirement to use fragments, then I would recommend using HomeDetailActivity instead of HomeDetailFragment.

Most of your above code will remain the same except you will be calling an Activity(via an intent) instead of a Fragment.

This has certain advantages like you don't have to deal with fragmentManager or fragment backStack. In your case it's quite easy to implement.

Comment: I agree with you, before I have tried using HomeDetailActivity. but I am progressing because it overrides bottom navigationview. thank you for your attention, make me enough by using fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to open up a new fragment on recycler view item click. am i right ?

Comment: Yeah. I've done it like opening a new fragment. But why such a result? Is this annoyed because I instanced bottom navigationview?